# Can't see the map from the HelloWorld example ArcGIS android SDK

Tags: java, android, xml, arcgis

I tried the Hello World code from ArcGIS android SDK and followed all the steps but the map doesn't appear and instead I get a black mapview.

Here is the java code :

```
package com.example.user.arcgismap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.esri.android.map.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MapView mMapView;

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    // After the content of this Activity is set, the map can be accessed programmatically from the layout.
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Call MapView.pause to suspend map rendering while the activity is paused, which can save battery usage.
    if (mMapView != null)
    {
        mMapView.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Call MapView.unpause to resume map rendering when the activity returns to the foreground.
    if (mMapView != null)
    {
        mMapView.unpause();
    }
}
}
```

and here is the xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.user.arcgismap.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<com.esri.android.map.MapView
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
mapoptions.MapType="streets"
mapoptions.center="34.056215, -117.195668,"
mapoptions.ZoomLevel="16">
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

can anyone help, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't need a license configuration for that?

Comment: No I don't think so, nothing mentioned in the Install and set up page nor in the examples. unless I am missing something ...

Comment: I double checked apparently for developing and testing the map the free account is enough but for deploying the app I need a licence to do so

Answer (score 0):

apparently the code is working well all I had to do was to reinstall the apk and wait a little bit for the map to load. I guess patience is a virtue.